# jQuery AJAX Script returning parseerror

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a sign up form that I'm building and the AJAX code that is supposed to handle the form submission keeps returning parseerror.
I'm using Material Design Framework.

This is the jQuery code:

//Form Submission

```
$form.submit(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 800);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/libraries/signup.php',            
        dataType: "text",
        data: {
            firstName: $fName.val(),
            otherNames: $oName.val(),
            userEmail: $uEmail.val(),
            phoneNumber: $pNumber.val(),
            userPassword: $uPassword.val(),
            userGender: $gender.val(),
            accType: $accType.val(),
            submit: 'Sign Up'
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#p2").fadeIn(120);
            $("div.error").fadeOut(380).empty();
            showToast("Please Wait...");
        },
        success: function (response) {
            $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
            if (response.type === "success") {
                showToast(response.content);
            } else {
                $("div.error").slideUp().html(response.content).fadeIn(500);
                setTimeout('$("div.error").fadeOut(500);', 3500);
                $("#p2").fadeOut(320);
            }
        },
        error: function (jXHR, textStatus) {
            $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);

            $("div.error").slideUp().html("Couldn't submit request: " + textStatus).fadeIn(500);
            setTimeout('$("div.error").fadeOut(500);', 5500);
            $("#p2").fadeOut(320);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

And this is the PHP:

```
//Configurations File
include dirname(__FILE__)."/functions.php";

//Check Form Submission
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" && $_POST['submit'] == "Sign Up"){

    //Sanitize and Encrypt User Input
    $firstName = filterUserInput($_POST['firstName']);
    $otherNames = filterUserInput($_POST['otherNames']);
    $userEmail = filterUserInput($_POST['userEmail']);
    $phoneNumber = filterUserInput($_POST['phoneNumber']);
    $userPassword = filterUserInput($_POST['userPassword']);
    $gender = filterUserInput($_POST['userGender']);
    $accountType = filterUserInput($_POST['accType']);  

    registerMember($firstName, $otherNames, $userEmail, $phoneNumber, $userPassword, $gender, $accountType, $db);
}
```

I have tried several methods and viewed so many solutions online, but the problem still persists.
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: What is $form? You should use something like this $( "#formID" ).submit(function( event ) {});

Comment: dataType should be JSON right? Also, try to be consistent with double and single quotes. Is the path to the URL correct? What error message do you get?

Comment: @Nirali `$form` is probably `$("form")` something and saved as `$form`....

Comment: Please add a [mcve] that shows the problem.

Comment: Where you define all this variables $fName,..?

Comment: @Nirali This is how I defined those variables

`var $form = $("form#sign-up-form");`
`var $fName = $("input#first-name-field");`
`var $oName = $("input#other-names-field");`
`var $uEmail = $("input#user-email-field");`
`var $pNumber = $("input#phone-number-field");`
`var $uPassword = $("input#user-password-field");`
`var $cPassword = $("input#confirm-password-field");`
`var $gender = $("input#gender");`
`var $accType = $("input#account-type");`

Comment: @Refilon I tried using JSON as dataType but it returned parseerror anytime I submitted the form.
The "text" dataType to doesn't work, but this one doesn't output anything at all.

Comment: what is the actual error message text?

Comment: See a screenshot showing the problem in action [here](allmyfiles.000webhostapp.com/Screenshot%20(20).png)
And the zip file containing the whole project [here](allmyfiles.000webhostapp.com/justbeingpaid.zip)